# .NET6: How to implement Dependency Injection from controller to service and from service to DbContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to figure out Dependency Injection with .NET6. I have in my Visual Studio 2022 solution, one project having one controller. The controller constructor has an interface `IWorkstationService`, which I want to inject.

```
    public class WorkstationsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IWorkstationService m_workstationService;

        public WorkstationsController(IWorkstationService workstationService)
        {
            m_workstationService = workstationService;
        }
```

In another project, I implemented the service which has a DbContext in its constructor which I want injected:

```
    public class WorkstationServiceImpl : IWorkstationService
    {
        private GCS156Context m_dbContext;

        public WorkstationServiceImpl(GCS156Context dbContext)
        {
            m_dbContext = dbContext;
        }
```

In my first project, I have the following in the Program.cs file:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:Gcs156");
    builder.Services.AddSqlServer<GCS156Context>(connectionString);
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IWorkstationService, WorkstationServiceImpl>();
    var app = builder.Build();
```

Here is the constructor for my DbContext:

```
public partial class GCS156Context : DbContext
{
    public GCS156Context()
    {
    }

    public GCS156Context(DbContextOptions<GCS156Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

The problem is that the first project (where I have my controller) is not compiling.
I get the Exception below. But I don't know how to fix this. Should I register the `DbContext` in the DI Container in the first project too? I don't understand why I should. It's not being used in the first project, it is used in the second project, the service.

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BlazorApp1.Database.Service.IWorkstationService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BlazorApp1.Workstations.Service.WorkstationServiceImpl': Unable to resolve service for type 'BlazorApp1.Database.Service.Models.GCS156Context' while attempting to activate 'BlazorApp1.Workstations.Service.WorkstationServiceImpl'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\rayca\source\repos\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Server\Program.cs:line 14

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BlazorApp1.Database.Service.IWorkstationService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BlazorApp1.Workstations.Service.WorkstationServiceImpl': Unable to resolve service for type 'BlazorApp1.Database.Service.Models.GCS156Context' while attempting to activate 'BlazorApp1.Workstations.Service.WorkstationServiceImpl'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BlazorApp1.Database.Service.Models.GCS156Context' while attempting to activate 'BlazorApp1.Workstations.Service.WorkstationServiceImpl'.
```

Comment: Exactly what version of EF are you using?

Comment: I'm using EF Core  6.0.1

Comment: Can you post GCS156Context header and constructors pls? Does it have  any  base dbcontext?

Comment: @Serge I added the GCS156Context constructor in my question.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using this syntax for many years, and never had any problem

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GCS156Context>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Gcs156")));
```

Comment: Why? Here is an `AddSqlServer` extension method on [`IServiceCollection`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/08e5ebd4f6218712590bcd8e3f9807be778b5bde/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L58) which adds db context.

Comment: @GuruStron Why??? Because AddSqlServer failed. It is the first time I can see that dbcontext can not be created.

Comment: Check out the link I've attached to the previous comment and see what `AddSqlServer` actually does.

Comment: @GuruStron I see this code  for the first time. So I am sure that 99.99% people use the syntax I posted and nobody from them have  been ever complaining

Comment: If you don't know something it does not mean that it is wrong or differs from what you are suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) for Blazor apps you need to use `AddDbContextFactory` since:

> Some application types (e.g. ASP.NET Core Blazor) use dependency injection but do not create a service scope that aligns with the desired DbContext lifetime. Even where such an alignment does exist, the application may need to perform multiple units-of-work within this scope. For example, multiple units-of-work within a single HTTP request.

So you need to change `builder.Services.AddSqlServer<GCS156Context>(connectionString);` to something like:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<GCS156Context>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

[ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core (EFCore)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0#new-dbcontext-instances)

Comment: I also found this page where using the factor is an option, but unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: @Ray do you use Blazor Server or Blazor WASM? Also check out  [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope).

Comment: I created a hosted Blazor WASM which created also a Blasor Server. In the server, I added controllers which use a service to update the database. The service is in another project which uses the DbContext. I'm trying to inject the service into the controller. It is the server's Program.cs file that is giving me the above error. It is complaining that the service cannot be activated because of the DbContext.